# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Dispongo del siguiente dataframe:

```
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 658 entries, 2016-01-04 to 2019-01-31
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Equity    658 non-null float64
Equity    658 non-null float64
Equity    658 non-null float64
Equity    658 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 25.7 KB
```

Intento renombrar las columnas.

```
old_names = ['Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity' ] 
new_names = ['Equity1','Equity2', 'Equity3','Equity4' ]
data.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)
```

Me devuelve el error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-9f8bfefe3429> in <module>
      1 old_names = ['Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity' ]
      2 new_names = ['Equity1','Equity2', 'Equity3','Equity4' ]
----> 3 data.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

¿Cual puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un diccionario es un objeto perfectamente válido para el argumento `columns` de `pandas.DataFrame.rename`. Es casi seguro que tu error se debe a que antes de estás líneas en tu módulo has redefinido el tipo preconstruido (clase) `dict`. Es muy fácil reproducir tu error:

```
>>> type(dict)
<class 'type'>

>>> a = dict([["a", 4]])
>>> type(a)         
<class 'dict'>

>>> dict = a 
>>> b = dict([["b", 5]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

>>> type(dict)
<class 'dict'>
```

Con `dict = a` (o `dict = {}`) reasignas al identificador `dict` la referencia a un objeto `dict`, por lo que a partir de este momento, `dict` no es una clase que puedas instanciar para crear un nuevo diccionario, es un objeto de esta clase, y un diccionario no es callable (`{"a": 4}()`).

Por norma general, nunca debes usar los nombres de los [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) o de módulos de la stdlib para nombrar variables propias, a lo sumo (si no hay un nombre mejor) usa el nombre seguido de un guion bajo como marcan las convenciones:

```
 dict_ = {"a": 4}
```

Dicho esto, aún corrigiendo lo anterior, tal y como lo estás haciendo no vas a poder renombrar las columnas:

```
>>> old_names = ['Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity' ] 
>>> new_names = ['Equity1','Equity2', 'Equity3','Equity4' ]
>>> dict(zip(old_names, new_names))
{'Equity': 'Equity4'}
```

`zip(old_names, new_names)` genera:

```
(('Equity', 'Equity1'), ('Equity', 'Equity2'), ('Equity', 'Equity3'), ('Equity', 'Equity4'))
```

cuando usamos `dict` sobre lo anterior obtenemos:

```
{'Equity': 'Equity4'}
```

esto pasa porque los **diccionarios tienen clave única**, por lo que solo queda la última pareja, `('Equity', 'Equity4')`. Finalmente **resultará en un DataFrame con todas las columnas renombradas como `Equity4`**

Para tu caso, simplemente reasigna los nuevos nombres usando el atributo `DataFrame.columns`:

```
new_names = ['Equity1','Equity2', 'Equity3','Equity4' ]
data.columns = new_names
```